# Are $\alpha\beta$ or $\alpha+\beta$ trascendental over $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ a field and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ trascendental over
$F$. Prove that $\alpha\beta$ or $\alpha+\beta$ are trascendental
over $F$.

Comment: But yes, at least one of those two numbers is transcendental.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The way I read the question is "If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both transcendental over $\Bbb F$ then does it follow that at least one of $\alpha\beta$ or $\alpha+\beta$ are also transcendental over $\Bbb F$?"  All your comment shows so far is that it is possible for it to not be both simultaneously.

Comment: @JMoravitz In fact, I have to prove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** If $\alpha\beta$ and $\alpha +\beta$ are algebraic over $F$, then so are the solutions to 
$$x^2-(\alpha +\beta)x+\alpha\beta=0$$